# Windows Phone 7 Multiple Sounds Lag

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm making a drum machine. From what I've read, it looks like the [XNA SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx) class runs based on a timer, which causes a noticeable lag, and stops the rhythm being smooth.

I tried to use MediaElement, 'til I found out you cannot play multiple sounds at the same time.

Are there any workarounds for this? The sounds are handled by a timer, and need to play instantly.

Comment: Have you investigated how accurate that timer is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some in-game use of the XNA SoundEffect class and not seen any lag when responding to user events - e.g. button presses - especially when the sound effect is pre-loaded from resources.

The XNA class is designed to be used for sound effects - so it should be ideal for a single drum machine hit.

If you then see problems with timing on IsLooping, then I guess you'll have to implement your own timer to trigger new instances - but my advice would be to try it first.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by preloading. I had this code: [link](http://pastebin.com/haGvmFmM), and I commented out the old system that was laggy. Is that commented code what you were talking about? Thanks

Comment: Only difference I can see from my code is that I call Update() every time I play a sound. Just tried this again using Squares IV sample on "Iron7 Free" - every time I press the screen then there's no noticeable lag - and that's with IronRuby being used! Only other question I would have is: are you testing on the emulator or on a real phone?

Comment: Can't edit last message; I'm using the emulator, but an app I have on the marketplace also has a lag, but it goes after two or so runs.

Comment: I'm also assuming you are using a static instance of your DrumSoundMachine class - not using a new instance each time - that would definitely cause a lag! If you check out the xylophone or piano samples in "iron7 free" then they show no lag that I can spot - and that's with dynamic code being run inside Ruby on the phone!

Comment: I need a system-wide implementation. Would putting it in app.xaml.cs be better? Cheers.

Comment: For OO design reasons I wouldn't put the sound files themselves in app.xaml.cs - the only thing I wanted to check above was that you were using the same instance of DrumSoundMachine each time.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using some sound in my app and I used the code from the example given on the msdn code samples website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

It looks like they are updating the timer every 50ms. Also note that the `SoundEffect` variables (`coyoteSound` and `birdSound`) are private data members where they only load once. The event handler on the button clicks simply call `SoundEffect.play()`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadSound("Resources/NightAmbientCreatureOneShot_01.wav", out coyoteSound);
    LoadSound("Resources/AfternoonAmbientBirdOneShot_09.wav", out birdSound);
    LoadSoundInstance("Resources/NightAmbienceSimple_01.wav", out ambienceSound, out ambienceInstance);

    // Set the volume a little lower than full so it becomes the background.
    ambienceInstance.Volume = 0.8f;

    // Turn on looping so it runs continually in the background.
    ambienceInstance.IsLooped = true;

    // Timer to simulate the XNA game loop (SoundEffect classes are from the XNA Framework)
    DispatcherTimer XnaDispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    XnaDispatchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);

    // Call FrameworkDispatcher.Update to update the XNA Framework internals.
    XnaDispatchTimer.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };

    // Start the DispatchTimer running.
    XnaDispatchTimer.Start();
}
```